# Coordinates by hodometric position

Tags: r, shiny

I have a vector which is an oil line, it is georreferenced, but this line, as you can imagine, isn't straight. What I need is to find a way to get a coordinate point by it's hodometric position. eg.: What's the X,Y of the 400 meter position from it's beginning point?

I'd like to make it in R, but that's not a exigence, so I could create a shinyapp so the user could just input the hodometric position and find by himself the coordinates.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new yser, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You have multiple platforms tagged, and the Question asks about another.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, you can use QGIS expressions for that with function [`line_interpolate_point()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#line-interpolate-point). Use this expression to create a point 400 m from the start point of the line, measured along the line:

`line_interpolate_point ($geometry, 400)`

Enclose the expression in funtion [`x()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#id33) and [`y()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#y) to get x/y coordinates.